# How to enable HTTPS in Tomcat webapp hosted on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, https

I have looked after so many webpages and tutorials but every source is different from each other and I don't really know how to start and where to search. My scenario: I have launched a javascript webapp on a Tomcat which I installed on an AWS EC2 instance like it is done in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d-c9uGcUrU
Now I want to secure this webapp via HTTPS. So what I've done yet? I added port 443 to my security group and added 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 to the sources. Furthermore I edited the server.xml file in the Apache Tomcat conf directory, made the tomcat accessible under port 80 instead of 8080 and added a redirect to port 443:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />
```

But when I enter the URL https://ec2-[IPv4-adress].eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com in my browser I get a connection refused error. What else I should do to get this going? Do I need an extra SSL certificate for my AWS URL? And if yes is the AWS certificate manager the right way? It seems like I can enter every domain in the world in the certificate formular. That confuses me. I just want the ec2-[...].eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ URL to use HTTPS so what should I enter there?

Comment: You have to install an SSL certificate in Tomcat first, and open port 443, before you start redirecting traffic to port 443. What do you mean by "extra SSL certificate"? If there is pertinent information in that video you linked to, like if you are using a load balancer or something, include that in the question. Please don't expect busy people offering to give you free help to spend their time watching a video.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to install an SSL certificate in Tomcat like you said but I have a problem: First I created a self-signed certificate and added a connector attribute in the server.xml. The certificate worked but there was a 'The connection is not secure' error in the browsers. I found out that it is necessary to create a ca certificate. I used zerossl for that but when I try to create one I have to verify the domain and have to add the cname record. Where can I do that in AWS? Sorry I'm very new to this whole SSL stuff.